# Using DatePicker Inside a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, modal-dialog

Im trying to assign an input text field a datepicker value however because it's in a modal i am having trouble. It could even be because i dont know what scripts and stylesheets to bring in. Here's the code

```
// A simple callback implementation.
function pickerCallback(data) {
  if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
    var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
    $('#\\#myModal').modal('show');
 }
}

$(date).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
    var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    var options={
      format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
      container: container,
      todayHighlight: true,
      autoclose: true,
    };
    date_input.datepicker(options);
  })


</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

<div id="result"></div>
<!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=loadPicker"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="#myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-  label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Set Metadata</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
     Department ID: <select id = "drop" style="margin-bottom: 0.25cm;">
    <option value="#001">#001---Law</option>
    <option value="#002">#002---Sales</option>
    <option value="#003">#003---Tech</option>
  </select>
    <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
        Date:<input type="text" id = "date" style="margin-left: 60px; margin-bottom: 0.25cm;" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY"/>
    </div>
    Additional Tag: <input type="text" id="metadata" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em; margin-bottom: 0.25cm;" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('set_tag').click();"/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="setMeta(document.getElementById('drop').value)">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
<!--End Modal-->
     </body>
   </html>
```

I just want it so that when the if statement at the top occurs, the modal dialog appears (which it does) but it appears with the datepicker in the textbox. If anyone knows a fix that'd be great.

Comment: By `$(date).ready(function(){` do you mean `$(document).ready(function(){`?

Comment: Im dumb, thanks youre right that worked. I spent too long staring at that for it to be a type

Comment: So did that fix your problem?

Comment: Ya man thanks! As i said I clearly had a long day